# VIM script to surround multiline comment with comment character

Tags: vim

For header style comments (including major new sections of code within the file) at my place of work, we use the following standard:

```
##################################
# This is a multiline comment    #
# and we've surrounded it by the #
# comment symbol.                #
##################################
```

When there's a lengthy multiline comment (as there so often is in descriptive headers), this can take a minute.  It's such a trivial task that I'd like to automate it.  My goal is to write a script that allows me to select a range (in visual mode), enter the command, and enter the comment character, resulting in enclosing the selected lines in a box like above. I've made some attempts at a VIM script, but honestly, having never written a VIM script before, my code is a mess, and I think it would actually be detrimental to the cause to post it.

Any suggestions as to how to go about building this?

Comment: That "company standard" is cumbersome to maintain; as you need an elaborate function to do this even in very powerful Vim, it won't be easier / automatable in other editors. At least drop the trailing aligned `#` characters; that makes it way easier to format.

Comment: @alaprise FYI:  https://github.com/sk1418/blockit  :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you don't need "minutes" to do that job. with vim's `ctrl-v` block selection with `I or c` and `r (replace)` you could do that pretty easy. However if you need do it 100 times a day, this little function may help you:

```
let g:wrap_char = '#'
function! WrapThem() range
    let lines = getline(a:firstline,a:lastline)
    let maxl = 0
    for l in lines
        let maxl = len(l)>maxl? len(l):maxl
    endfor
    let h = repeat(g:wrap_char, maxl+4)
    for i in range(len(lines))
        let ll = len(lines[i])
        let lines[i] = g:wrap_char . ' ' . lines[i] . repeat(' ', maxl-ll) . ' ' . g:wrap_char
    endfor  
    let result = [h]
    call extend(result, lines)
    call add(result,h)
    execute a:firstline.','.a:lastline . ' d'
    let s = a:firstline-1<0?0:a:firstline-1
    call append(s, result)
endfunction
```

source that file, note that

- the `g:wrap_char` you could set any char for your border, here I used `#`.
- you can visual select lines and wrap them with the char
- you can give range in command line by calling the function
- you could create your own command as a wrapper of that function or create mappings

A little demo:

[image]

Comment: What are you using to create the GIF? This is fantastic!

Comment: This is fantastic, and I learned a ton going over your source.  Thanks so much for putting this together for me!

Comment: It should be noted that this only works with printable ASCII characters. A tab character or any non-ASCII will break the right alignment. `len()` is byte length; you need to use `strdisplaywidth()` instead!

Comment: @IngoKarkat you are absolutely right. thank you so much for pointing it out.

Comment: @alfredodeza it is byzanz, with my own wrapper: https://github.com/sk1418/myScripts/blob/master/shell/recWin.sh

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend diving into either [NERDcommenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter/) or [tcomment](https://github.com/vim-scripts/tComment) if these plugins have the desired functionality before reinventing the wheel. If not, their source can be a good starting point.